Как сделать батник на запуск python-скрипта на ОС Win?
Всех приветствую!
У меня есть исходник со скриптом, написанный не мной. Мне нужно выполнить настройку автозапуска скрипта на ОС Windows. По найденным статьям на просторах интернета поняла, что нужно сделать bat-файл, но не нашла подробной инструкции, как это сделать. Помогите пожалуйста.

Плохо искали - в Инете куча информации об этом. Единственное что надо знать, что это будет не бат-файл, а самораспаковывающийся  архив.

@Алексей, можно подробнее? Например, ссылку на статью?

Для старта питон-скрипта в винде проще всего создать ярлык (см. windows - ярлыки) на python.exe, где в свойствах после python.exe указан путь к скрипту) Далее этот ярлык можно расположить в папку автозапуска (папка C:\Users\<ваше имя пользователя>\главное меню\Программы\Startup  на русской винде), если хотите запуска при старте, или на рабочий стол, если хотите просто по клику.

@AlexTitov я бы через батник+планировщик задач сделал, так намного удобней как по мне

@Amgarak, так и сделала. Только поначалу там были ошибки, потом я выставила абсолютный путь до скрипта и всё заработало.

@AlexTitov, спасибо за информацию, но мне нужен был запуск по времени, через батник удалось сделать

Вопрос снят, всем спасибо

Можете оформить ответ на свой вопрос, приложив содержимое батника.

Ответ простой, но к нему я шла несколько часов путём изучения информации в интернете. Чтобы скрипт Python работал через автозапуск, достаточно сделать bat-ник с таким содержимым:
python.exe E:\GoogleBackup\main.py, где
E:\GoogleBackup\main.py - путь на скрипт.
При этом в различных статьях встречаются такие варианты:
C:\Programm Files\Python312\python.exe E:\GoogleBackup\main.py и python.exe main.py, но у меня представленные варианты не работали.
Создала bat-ник, который windows спокойно запускает через автозапуск (Планировщик задач, если кто не знает).

Просто если путь с пробелами, то его нужно брать в кавычки. Без кавычек работать не будет, да.

@CrazyElf, так у меня все пути без пробелов

Я про C:\Programm Files\Python312\python.exe
